# Calculate real GDP

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

1. Assume that the annual growth GDP per capita is 2%, how much will the real GDP per capita increase in 10 years.
   I know the manual way is to take 2 percent every years. 
   For example after 1 year would be (100 x 2 )/100 = 2. So it would be a total of 102. Is there a formula to calculate the percent after 10 years?
2. Let’s say that China’s per capita GDP grow 9% a year for the next 16 years and 6% a year for the next 24 years. What is China’s per capita GDP in 40 years
   Well this one is kind of the same with the first one, is there a formula to calculate the percentage only.
   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Value of GDP every year is in geometric progression with common ratio being 102/100
For value of gdp per capita in nth year, just find the value of (n-1)th term in the geometric progression.

Comment: Can you please do an example?

Answer (score 0):

A hint for part 2.  To obtain an approximate answer, it's convenient to use the rule that the doubling time $D$ in years of a quantity growing exponentially at a constant annual rate $r$ is given approximately by the [rule of 72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72):

$$D = \frac{72}{r}$$

Given the assumptions in your question the numbers work out very neatly.